# What's the difference between "я русский" and "я русская"

Tags: грамматика

What's the difference between "я русский" and "я русская"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Я русский** would be spoken by a male, whereas **Я русская** would be spoken by a female. And to complete the picture, **Мы русские** would be spoken by two or more people.

Comment: In detail, the adjective "русский" is here being applied to the pronoun "я". When adjectives are applied to a (pro)noun in Russian, they get a different ending depending on the noun's gender (and case, and number). See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Russian/Grammar/Adjectives#Summary).